# How tho change Websphere Application server v8.5.5, v9 SystemOut.log timestamp pattern

Tags: logging, design-patterns, timestamp, websphere, application-server

does anyone know how I can change the timestamp pattern in the SystemOut.log log on the Websphere Application Server  v8.5.5, v9?
For example, instead of **[1/24/23 8:10:43:524 CET]** I want to see **[2023-01-24T10:43:00,003]**